# Problems with executing second SQL statement within a private class in PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm working on a script that processes form data: A few text fields and 2 files, one an image, one a doc. I have placed two sql statements on the page, the first inserts the text field data and retrieves the id of the row. The second one updates that row with the urls of the two files.

The second sql statement is not executing, although the files are saving to the server. This is my first time using Private classes in PHP and also the first time using PDO.

I'm clearly doing something wrong and was wondering if someone can see where my issue(s) are.

```
   <?php
require('../dbcon2.php');
//Connection 1
try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO listings (title, address, transaction, date_added) VALUES (:title, :address, :transaction, now())");
          $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']); 
          $stmt->bindParam(':address', $_POST['address']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':transaction', $_POST['transaction']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $lastid = $conn->lastInsertId();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
//Create class
    class CropAvatar {
        private $src;
        private $data;
        private $file;
        private $dst;
        private $type;
        private $extension;
        private $srcDir = '../0images/listimg/orig';
        private $dstDir = '../0images/listimg/mod';
        private $msg;

function __construct($src, $data, $file, $lastid) {
    $this -> setSrc($src);
    $this -> setId($lastid);
    $this -> setData($data);
    $this -> setFile($file);
    $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data);
}
        private $lastid;
        public function setId($lastid) {
                 $this->id = $lastid;
}
        private function setSrc($src) {
            if (!empty($src)) {
                $type = exif_imagetype($src);
                if ($type) {
                    $this -> src = $src;
                    $this -> type = $type;
                    $this -> extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                    $this -> setDst();
                }
            }
        }
        private function setData($data) {
            if (!empty($data)) {
                $this -> data = json_decode(stripslashes($data));
            }
        }
        private function setFile($file) {
            $errorCode = $file['error'];
            if ($errorCode === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $type = exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']);
                if ($type) {
                    $dir = $this -> srcDir;
                    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                        mkdir($dir, 0777);
                       }
                    $currdate=date('YmdHis');
                    $extension = image_type_to_extension($type);
                    $src = $dir . '/' . $currdate . $extension;
                    if ($type == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG || $type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
                        if (file_exists($src)) {
                            unlink($src);
                        }
                    $result = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $src);
                    $listing_img="http://www.WEBSITE.com/0images/listimg/mod/" . $currdate . $extension;
 //Process file upload 
                    $allowedExtsf = array("pdf");
                    $tempf = explode(".", $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                    $extensionf = end($tempf);
                    if (($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
                    && ($_FILES["flyer"]["type"] <2000000000)
                    && in_array($extensionf, $allowedExtsf)) 
                    {
                        $flyername=$_FILES["flyer"]["name"];
                        if ($_FILES["flyer"]["error"] > 0) 
                        {
                        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["flyer"]["error"] . "<br>";
                        }   
                                if (file_exists("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"])) 
                                {
                                    unlink("../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                                    $ad_link="http://www.WEBSITE.com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];
                                }
                                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["flyer"]["tmp_name"],"../flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"]);
                                    $ad_link="http://www.website.com/flyers/" . $_FILES["flyer"]["name"];
                        }                   
      //Connection 2
      require('../dbcon2.php');
      try {
          global $last_id;
          $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
          $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          $sql="UPDATE listings SET ad_link='$ad_link', listing_img='$listing_img' WHERE id=$this->id";
          $conn->exec($sql);
          }
      catch(PDOException $e)
          {
          echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
          }
      $conn = null;

      //Error handling
                        if ($result) {
                            $this -> src = $src;
                            $this -> type = $type;
                            $this -> extension = $extension;
                            $this -> setDst();
                        } 
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        private function setDst() {
            $dir = $this -> dstDir;
            if (!file_exists($dir)) {
                mkdir($dir, 0777);
            }

            $this -> dst = $dir . '/' . date('YmdHis') . $this -> extension;
        }
        private function crop($src, $dst, $data) {
            if (!empty($src) && !empty($dst) && !empty($data)) {
                switch ($this -> type) {
                    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src);
                        break;

                    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                        break;

                    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                        $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                        break;
                }

                if (!$src_img) {
                    $this -> msg = "Failed to read the image file";
                    return;
                }
                $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor(220, 220);
                $result = imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $data -> x, $data -> y, 220, 220, $data -> width, $data -> height);
                if ($result) {
                    switch ($this -> type) {
                        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                            $result = imagegif($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;

                        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                            $result = imagejpeg($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;

                        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                            $result = imagepng($dst_img, $dst);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                imagedestroy($src_img);
                imagedestroy($dst_img);
            }
        }
        private function codeToMessage($code) {
            switch ($code) {

                default:
                    $message = 'Unknown upload error';
            }

            return $message;
        }
        public function getResult() {
            return !empty($this -> data) ? $this -> dst : $this -> src;
        }
        public function getMsg() {
            return $this -> msg;
        }
    }
$crop = new CropAvatar($_POST['avatar_src'], $_POST['avatar_data'], $_FILES['avatar_file'], $lastid);
    $response = array(
        'state'  => 200,
        'message' => $crop -> getMsg(),
        'result' => $crop -> getResult()
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: You may have a scope issue as you are trying to use `$ad_link`/`$listing_img` in your update query, which are only available in their respective functions. Try saving them as class properties, and access them that way.

Comment: Do you get any sort of exception printed that you could share ?!